# Array on photo gallery not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have problem with my JS script below. I created a photo gallery with a caption below each of them. I used array to create the caption. However, on the first page, the caption is 1; on the second page, the caption is ,(comma); on the third, the caption is 2; on the fourth page, the caption is ,(comma), etc. I want that the caption is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. I confused why the comma can be the caption. Are there any solution ?

```js
var num;
var name = ["", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

function change(n) {
  num = n;
  var path = "img/" + n + '.png';
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = name[n];
  document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = path;
  return false;
}

function next() {
  if (num >= 6) {
    num = 1;
  } else {
    num = num + 1;
  }

  change(num);
}

function prev() {
  if (num <= 1) {
    num = 6;
  } else {
    num = num - 1;
  }

  change(num);
}
```

```html
<body onload="change(1)">
  <a href="#" onclick="prev()">Prev</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(1)">1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(2)">2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(3)">3</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(4)">4</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(5)">5</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(6)">6</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="next()">Next</a>

  <br>
  <br>
  <img src="" alt="" style="width:600px; height:320px">
  <br>
  <p id="text"></p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you define `name` in the global scope it overwrites the `window.name` property which is string, as a result your array is converted into a string `,1,2,3,4,5,6` instead of array. Use a different variable name like `names` to avoid that. Also the best would be to use event handlers and separate your html from the javascript and you will be able to use namespaces that will not pollute the `window` object with global variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: Then why does the type not change like with (function(){
    window.test = 'test good!';
    
    var test = [1,2,3];
    
    alert(test[2]);
    
    
})();

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `name` array something else. `name` refers to `windows.name` and if you assign a value to this variable it is treated as a string.

```js
var num;
var namedata = ["", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];


function change(n) {
  num = n;
  var path = "img/" + n + '.png';
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = namedata[n];
  //document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = name
  document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = path;
  return false;
}

function next() {
  if (num >= 6) {
    num = 1;
  } else {
    num = num + 1;
  }

  change(num);
}

function prev() {
  if (num <= 1) {
    num = 6;
  } else {
    num = num - 1;
  }

  change(num);
}
```

```html
<body onload="change(1)">
  <a href="#" onclick="prev()">Prev</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(1)">1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(2)">2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(3)">3</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(4)">4</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(5)">5</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(6)">6</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="next()">Next</a>

  <br>
  <br>
  <img src="" alt="" style="width:600px; height:320px">
  <br>
  <p id="text"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: I also found this, but I am still wondering why we cannot use `name` as variable name?